# (C#) Convert int type to address type

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I can compile a code like this

```
unsafe static void Main()
{
  int i = 5;
  int* j = &i;
}
```

But how can I convert address type to int type and vice versa? like:

```
unsafe static void Main()
{
  int i = 5;
  int _j = (int)&i;
  int* j = (AddressType)_j;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires unsafe code?

Comment: I want app1 and app2 can access the same memory location, not access  the same file(too slow),  just for fun and curious.

Comment: @DaveG You're not going to be able to do that with just pointers.  That's what [memory-mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) are for.

Comment: Try to be a little more curious about how much every virus scanner on earth would freak out over such an operation if it were possible...

Comment: It is for semiconductor equipment that are totally free of anti-virus software and internet, I am try to write a application that can trace every source code line.

Comment: In a 64-bit application, the address would be 64-bit as well, but `int` is only 32-bit. Additionally, you cannot access the memory of another application through pointers only, you need to use special functions to read and write memory in another process, or set up some shared memory.

Comment: @Kyle I take a look at memory-mapped files, so the address that app1 get won't be the same in app2 in real storage location, so it is impossible to achieve this goal I guess

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen  Thanks, I know that, but I need access the memory really fast or it will delay the equipment operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you are tying to achieve; you'd have to cast that to int before you could get pointer. But that is a pointer to a pointer address.

```
    enum AddressType
    {
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e
    }
    unsafe static void Main()
    {

        int i = 2;
        int _j = (int)&i;
        int k = (int)(AddressType)_j;
        int* j = &k; 

        int l = *j;
        var s = (int*) l;
        int m = *s; 

        Console.WriteLine(m);

        var r = AddressType.b;
        AddressType* x = &r;
        AddressType y = *x;

        Console.WriteLine(y);

    }
```

Comment: So how can I get the '2' back from this? *j is still an address

Comment: I've put two different approaches to achieve what you wanted. In above code int m would get back your '2' but in the second approach I'd just do enum pointer and retrieve it back.